# Running Matlab function from linux command line -- syntax error?

Tags: linux, bash, matlab, command-line

I have a matlab function `checkMembraneSpline.m`, and I want to run this in the command line using the matlab command. I tried the following

```
matlab -r -nodisplay -nojvm "checkMembraneSpline(10,1000,'',100,500,2.5); catch; end; quit"
```

which returns this cryptic error:

```
/opt/apps/rhel7/matlabR2019a/bin/matlab: eval: line 1734: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/opt/apps/rhel7/matlabR2019a/bin/matlab: eval: line 1734: `exec  "/admin/apps/rhel7/matlabR2019a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB"  -r "-nodisplay" checkMembraneSpline(10,1000,'',100,500,2.5); catch; end; quit -nojvm'
```

However, when I launch matlab by doing `matlab -nojvm -nodisplay` and running the function from there by

```
>>> checkMembraneSpline(10,1000,'',100,500,2.5)
```

it works. I suspected it was something to do with the quotation marks, but switching `"` with `'` also doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement has to come right after the `-r` switch:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -r "checkMembraneSpline(10,1000,'',100,500,2.5); catch; end; quit"
```

If you have a newer version of MATLAB, use the `-batch` switch instead:

```
matlab -nojvm -batch "checkMembraneSpline(10,1000,'',100,500,2.5);"
```

With this new switch you don’t need to have an `exit` call, it always quits after competing the statement. Therefore, it is also not necessary to catch errors. Output is put into the terminal by default. Much simpler!

Reference: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html